# Finding foci, asymptotes, and a vertices of a hyperbola given an equation

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, parametric

I'm given the equation $4x^2-y^2-24x-6y+23$ and asked to find the foci, vertices and asymptotes. The book showed me how to do it given an equation in the form of $(x^2/a)-(y^2/b)=1$, but didn't show me how to handle anything like this and I don't know what to do with it in this form. Where do I even start with this?

Comment: Try "completing the square" to absorb the 6y term.

Comment: Try recalling your study of linear transformations (especially translations).

Comment: Thanks, Coffeemath. Never knew about completing the square... Going to have to look up the other thing John mentioned too....

Comment: My best understood method to identify asymptote with least memorization - once you have equation, make the sign positive. Form the eclipse, and draw the rectangle around it. The diagonals form the asymptotes.